# When I try to use variable that is result of object destructuring TS does not recognize its type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use variable from destructuring expression as part of another object but Typescript does not recognize its type correctly.

Here is an example what I'm doing:

```js
// some data structure
type Data = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  tags: string[];
  documents: [{ name: string; content: string }];
};

// just generate dummy data
const getData = (): Data => ({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  email: 'john.doe@example.com',
  tags: ['javascript', 'typescript'],
  documents: [{ name: 'cv.pdf', content: '...' }],
});

const processData = (data: {
  // why this type does not cover meta from rest operator?
  [key: string]:
    | string
    | string[]
    | { [key: string]: string }[]
    | { [key: string]: string };
}): void => {
  console.log(data);
};

// destructure with rest
const { email, tags, documents, ...meta } = getData();

// why TS does not recognize type here?
processData({ email, tags, documents, meta });
```

and this is error that I get

```
 error TS2322: Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | { [key: string]: string; } | { [key: string]: string; }[]'.
  Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
    Index signature is missing in type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; }'.

50 processData({ email, tags, documents, meta });
                                         ~~~~

  src/example.ts:37:3
     37   [key: string]:
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     38     | string
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ... 
     40     | { [key: string]: string }[]
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     41     | { [key: string]: string };
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because in TS types are not *sealed*, meaning they express required fields but don't disallow excess properties. Therefore it is possible to add properties to `meta` that don't comply with the index signature you're expecting in `processData`, (i.e. by means of `Object.assign(meta, { id: 4234 })`).

A possible fix would be to destrucutre `meta` into a new object.

```js
processData({ email, tags, documents, {...meta} });
```

or to define a constraint for additional properties in Data:

```js
type Data = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  tags: string[];
  documents: [{ name: string; content: string }];
  [key: string]: string | string[] | {name: string, content: string}[];
};
```

Comment: I did just that as a workaround but this is not root cause of problem since this example works: ```type SpecificType = {firstName: string, lastName: string};
type AbstractType = {[key: string]: string};
const s: SpecificType = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'};
const a: AbstractType = s;```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer to reward your efforts but still wondering what is issue with destructuring and types...